# Java - can Sockets be used for accessing remote objects?

Tags: java, rmi

I have learnt the basics of creating Sockets and RMI.

The question is on what can Sockets be used for? I saw this post in SO about using sockets to send a String object to a Server program.

[Java: Sockets or RMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2620687/547453)

So, after getting this String object in the Server, I could access the database and store it? And when the client need to access this String object, how could the Server retrive it database and send it to the Client? Can this be done using **only** Sockets?

I know we can do this using RMI.

Comment: What's the question? The one in your title, or the one in your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets provide a low level access to network streams, pretty much everything else is built on top of `Socket` or `ServerSocket` instances.

RMI uses sockets to implement a standard protocol for an RMI server and RMI client to communicate with.

Basically using sockets you can implement anything network based as long as it runs on TCP (or UDP if you use `DatagramSocket` instances)

In this case if you need extra performance you would use sockets because you don't have the overhead of the RMI protocol to slow down the communication.

In RMI you would return a String and everything would be wrapped up by the RMI for you, but if you go with sockets, you serialise the String using an `ObjectOutputStream` from the server and deserialise with an `ObjectInputStream` at the client.

Comment: @Chris...I sure understand this part....but when the client needs this String/MyOwnObject retrieved from the Server, how can it tell the server it wants this String/MyOwnObject back so that the Client can do whatever it wants. In RMI , I can call different methods in the remote object (like....one method to store data and another method to retrieve data).

Comment: Well like you say RMI does this for you, with sockets you have to implement your own protocol.

So the first thing the client would have to send is something to identify the type of request it is making, then your server would have to read this information and use it to respond with the correct data that is being requested.

Comment: I have no idea about implementing my own protocol. Can you point me in the right direction where I can learn about creating my own protocol? So far I have created Sockets that use TCP protocol.

Comment: The TCP protocol is the network layer tat ensures that data gets back and forth between server and client.  I'm taking about defining the requests the client will make and the responses the server will send back.  For example a client request might be "getTime", and the server would respond with the time in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS+HH:MM" fror example.  You are defining what you will support.  It sounds like you would be better off sticking to RMI for now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could serialize your Java object, create a stream that you could send over socket connection, then read the stream and deserialize it.
This + some utilities is basically what RMI does. But you could do it yourself if you are so inclined.

Something like this:

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();   
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);   
TestObj obj = (TestObj)ois.readObject();  

class TestObj implements Serializable {  
  //your class
}
```

Comment: @Roman...this would mean...I need to have *TestObj* class in both Server and Client package?

Comment: Yes, you would need the Class at both ends to serialise and deserialise.  Unless you are sending standard Java objects like back and forth between client and server.